# How do you remove a XML Element and All it's Multi-Level Children Using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, removechild

I'm trying to delete a particular a specific node in a XML structure. I want to be able to delete all of the children of the Employee element that contains the specific username that I specify from a form field and all the children that relate to it. I've been using SimpleXML to load in all the data, but I can reload in the data via another method. I'm wondering what the best method to delete all the Children no matter how many levels deep the element is. All the solutions that I've come across so far have only been one level deep. I would like to delete the user with the username `UserToDelete`. An example of the structure is as follows.

```
<Employees>
  <Employee Status="Part-time">
     <First_Name>...</First_Name>
     <Last_Name>...</Last_Name>
     <Position>...</Position>
     <SSN>...</SSN>
     <Contact_Info>
         <Office_Phone>...</Office_Phone>
         <Email>...</Email>
         <Cell_Phone>...</Cell_Phone>
     </Contact_Info>
     <Access_Info level="admin">
         <Username>UserToDelete</Username>
         <Password>...</Password>
     </Access_Info>
     <Department>...</Department>
     <Date_Started>...</Date_Started>
     <Salary>...</Salary>
     <Years>5</Years>
     <Photo>...</Photo>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>  
     ....
  </Employee>
  ...
</Employees>
```

So to the point of the question How do I delete the entire Employee using PHP including all of the children including the elements within the `contact_info` and `access_info`. Does it matter how many levels deep the nodes are or can I do something like the following?

```
foreach ($xml->Employee as $employee) {
    if($username == $employee->Access_Info->Username) {
        foreach ($family as $node) {
            $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
        }
        echo $dom->saveXML('employees.xml');
        echo "<font color='red'>".$username." deleted. </font>";
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

I am not getting an output on the `echo "<font color='red'>".$username." deleted. </font>";`.

Comment: Have you tested whether `$xml->Employee` contains any elements, and whether the `$username == $employee->Access_Info->Username` condition ever fires?

Comment: Well if I comment out the `echo $dom->saveXML('employees.xml');`. It echo's out the echo statement below. the xml data is being stored in employees.xml if it wasn't clear. So it's clearly getting the data from the xml object, especially considering that it's loading that in via SimpleXML and I use the same structure elsewhere.

Comment: What type variable is `$dom`, where does it come from? Do you have error reporting activated so you see if anything goes wrong with the `saveXML()` call? (This may be a problem unrelated to the actual XML)

Comment: `$dom = new DOMDocument; $dom->load('employees.xml');` here is the declaration of `$dom`.

Comment: "I would like to delete the user with the username UserToDelete"  There is no such thing as a 'user'.  Do you want to delete the whole Employee element?

Comment: yeah that's what the idea was to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So to the point of the question How do I delete the entire Employee

xml.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employees>

<Employee>
  <Username>Joe</Username>
  <Password>...</Password>
</Employee>


<Employee>
    <Access_Info level="admin">
      <Username>Jane</Username>
      <Password>...</Password>
    </Access_Info>
</Employee>


<Employee Status="Part-time">
     <First_Name>...</First_Name>
     <Last_Name>...</Last_Name>
     <Position>...</Position>
     <SSN>...</SSN>
     <Contact_Info>
         <Office_Phone>...</Office_Phone>
         <Email>...</Email>
         <Cell_Phone>...</Cell_Phone>
     </Contact_Info>
     <Access_Info level="admin">
       <NestedOneMoreTime>
         <Username>EmployeeToDelete</Username>
         <Password>...</Password>
       </NestedOneMoreTime>
     </Access_Info>
     <Department>...</Department>
     <Date_Started>...</Date_Started>
     <Salary>...</Salary>
     <Years>5</Years>
     <Photo>...</Photo>
</Employee>

</Employees>
```

php:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml");

foreach ($xml->Employee as $employee)
{
    //Because the needed xpath feature is broken in SimpleXML, create
    //a new xml document containing only the current Employee:
    $employee_xml = simplexml_load_string($employee->asXML()); 

    //Get all Username elements in employee_xml(there
    //should only be one, which will be at position 0 in the returned array):
    $usernames_array = $employee_xml->xpath("//Username");

    if($usernames_array[0] == "UserToDelete")
    {
        unset($employee[0]); //The first element of an Element object
                             //is a reference to its DOM location
        break; //Important--you don't want to keep iterating over something
               //from which you've deleted elements.  If you need to delete
               //more than one element, save the references in an array
               //and unset() them after this loop has terminated.
    }
}

echo $xml->asXML();
```